# Len function on a join clause

Tags: sql-server

```
Join db_abc
On a.userid = b.userid
```

I want to join all userid's in a on all user id's in b with length of 4.How can I specify a Len function on b.userid where userid length is 4 characters only? This is in SQL server

Comment: Is id an string or an ínteger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
JOIN db_abc b
    ON a.userid = b.userid
        AND LEN(b.userid) = 4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.userid = b.userid AND LEN(b.userid) = 4
```